# Is it possible to open and save an xls file using vbs without Excel installed?

Tags: excel, windows, vbscript

How can I mimic the functionalities of this script on a machine where no Excel installed:

1 loop through the subfolders
2. find xls file, then open, save and close

```vb
Dim objFSO, objFolder, objFile
Dim objExcel, objWB
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

ShowSubfolders FSO.GetFolder("path\to\mainFolder"), 3

Sub ShowSubFolders(Folder, Depth)
    If Depth > 0 Then
        For Each Subfolder In Folder.SubFolders
            For Each objFile In Subfolder.Files
                If Right(objFile.Name, 3) = "xls" Then
                    Set objWB = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(objFile)
                    objWB.Save
                    objWB.Close
                End If
            Next

            ShowSubFolders Subfolder, Depth-1
        Next
    End If
End Sub

objExcel.Quit
Set objExcel = Nothing
Set objFSO = Nothing
```

Comment: For what reason are you opening/saving/closing without changing the file?

Comment: The files are generated on PHP, and some system don't recognize them only by doing this.

Comment: Your code is using Excel's object model to open and save the file.  So no, you cannot use this code on a machine without Excel installed.

Comment: There are definitely ways with python, VB, C#, etc using other open source libraries that have similar syntax. I don't know how you would pull a third party library into VBS though.

Comment: The pragmatic solution would be to fix the PHP code that apparently generates faulty documents.

Answer (score 0):

Interop requires Excel to be installed on the machine.

You need to use a different Excel library, like [EasyXLS](https://www.easyxls.com).
Aside from other libraries, EasyXLS has also an [Excel component for VBS](https://www.easyxls.com/component-excel-library).

Your code looks like this:

```
Sub ShowSubFolders(Folder, Depth)
    If Depth > 0 Then
        For Each Subfolder In Folder.SubFolders
            For Each objFile In Subfolder.Files
                If Right(objFile.Name, 3) = "xls" Then
                    set objExcel = CreateObject("EasyXLS.ExcelDocument")
                    objExcel.easy_LoadXLSFile(objFile)
                    objExcel.easy_WriteXLSFile(objFileNew)
                End If
            Next

            ShowSubFolders Subfolder, Depth-1
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```